# sqlalchemy - data doesnt get pushed to database while commit but present in session(in memory)

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am adding data to sqlalchemy. But sometimes data is not getting updated or inserted to database. But the commit is successful and I can see the data in memory of session's object.
ie

```
session.identity_map
```

Running on sqlalchemy 1.3.3. python 2.7. ubuntu 18.04

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from . import Errors as ExecuteErrors

class Errors(object):
    def __init__(self, sqlalchemy_engine, d):
        self.sqlalchemy_engine = sqlalchemy_engine
        self.d = d

    def upsert(self, error):
        session = Session(self.sqlalchemy_engine)
        row = session.query(ExecuteErrors).filter_by(**{'c_name':error['c_name'], 'c_type':error['c_type'],
                                               'f_name':error['f_name']}).scalar()
        session.close()
        if row:
            self.update(error)
        else:
            self.insert(error)

    def insert(self, error):
        e = ExecuteErrors(**{'c_name':error['c_name'], 'c_type':error['c_type'], 'f_name':error['f_name'],
                          'msg':error['msg'], 'details':error['details']})
        session = Session(self.sqlalchemy_engine, expire_on_commit=False)
        session.add(e)
        session.identity_map
        session.commit()
        session.close()

    def update(self, error):
        session = Session(self.sqlalchemy_engine, expire_on_commit=False)
        session.query(ExecuteErrors).filter_by(**{'c_name':error['c_name'], 'c_type':error['c_type'],
                                               'f_name':error['f_name']}).update({'msg': error['msg'], 'details': error['details']})
        session.commit()
        session.close()

    def get_errors(self):
        session = Session(self.sqlalchemy_engine)
        e = session.query(ExecuteErrors).all()
        session.close()
        return e

    def clear(self):
        session = Session(self.sqlalchemy_engine)
        session.query(ExecuteErrors).delete()
        session.commit()
        session.close()
```

Calling this with:

```
e = Error(engine, 'emp')
e.upsert({'c_name':'filter','c_type':'task','f_name':'f1','msg':'TypeError','details':'xyz'})
```

This should add row in database or update row with new data.
Its working for some insert and for some not.

Answer (score 0):

You could find a possible workaround by explicitely [flushing](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#flushing) your session when needed.

That said, I think you should reconsider the way you're using sessions. Sessions are intended to manage database connections but you're using them as if there where actual connections.

IMHO, a better way to do would be to create a session at Error instanciation and use it when needed in all your methods.
An even better way to proceed could be to create a session at begining of your "calling" module and pass it to the Error instanciation, and to any other object which need access to database.
Doing this, you could even experience better performance and it may solve your problem (?)

More details about [how to manage sessions in the sqlalchemy doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it).

EDIT: In addition, the [sqlalchemy doc lists some potential problems when used with sqlite](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html#database-locking-behavior-concurrency). One of them could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Hi Tryph, Thank you for your answer !!  My problem got solved as I was passing wrong database name some times. I am thinking to do it with one time initialisation of session. But I have doubt that, when should I close the session or there is no need to close the session when I do this with one time session initialisation?

Comment: @poojadeokar You should close your session when you no more need database access. You can find more details in the sqlalchemy doc: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it